How to use io.BytesIO in Python to write to an existing buffer?
According to How the write(), read() and getvalue() methods of Python io.BytesIO work? , it seems io.BytesIO will copy initial bytes provided.
I have a buffer, and I want pickle to directly dump object in that buffer, without any copy. So I tried to use f = io.BytesIO(buffer). However, after f.write, my buffer is not modified.
Here is an example:
a = bytearray(1024)
import io
b = io.BytesIO(memoryview(a))
b.write(b"1234")
a[:4] # a does not change

What I want, is to make io.BytesIO directly writes to my buffer.
My ultimate goal is:
a = bytearray(1024)
import io, pickle
with io.BytesIO(memoryview(a)) as f:
    obj = [1, 2, 3]
    pickle.dump(obj, f)
# a should hold the pickled data of obj


A BytesIO is not a write-through object. It is an in-memory file-like object with its own storage.

@KlausD. thanks for your fast reply. Do you know any file-like object for write-through a provided memory?

What's the reason for using memoryview instead of just the bytearray?

@nocomment you can have a try. Directly passing bytearray will lead to error.

I tried. No error.

Indeed the memoryview is not necessary. My bad. I don't remember when it is needed.

IIUC you can try to make your own IO class:
import io
import pickle


class MyIO(io.IOBase):
    def __init__(self, buf):
        self.buf = memoryview(buf)
        self.position = 0

    def write(self, b):
        start = self.position
        n = len(b)
        end = start + n
        self.buf[start: end] = b
        self.position = end


a = bytearray(1024)
with MyIO(a) as f:
    obj = [1, 2, 3]
    pickle.dump(obj, f)

print(a)

Prints:
bytearray(b'\x80\x04\x95\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00]\x94(K\x01K\x02K\x03e.\x00\x00\x00  ...


This is probably the right idea, but for sane behavior you would need to implement the offset logic (tell / seek) and bounds checking. Write methods also generally return the number of bytes which were successfully written.

This is one possible solution. But I'm afraid putting this logic in Python would be slow.
Another concern is I don't want to re-invent the wheel. It seems to be a frequent usage, so I want to know if there is any existing solutions.

@youkaichao It's just copying the bytes to already allocated bytearray (thats implemented in C anyway), it should be fast.

@AndrejKesely great. I accepted your answer. Just want to know if any builtin functionality in Python does this, so that I didn't re-invent the wheel.

If you keep using a memoryview (I don't know why OP did), I think you could do self.buf[:n] = b and self.buf = self.buf[n:] instead of dealing with position.
